# How to change the default filter order in kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have set filterable attribute to true of kendo ui grid. When the filter is opened it lists all the filter options.It has a deopdown with 'And' and 'OR' option.
The dropdown shows first 'And' option and then the 'OR' option.

I have a requirement where I want to show first 'OR' option and then the 'And' option.

How can I do this. Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize filter menu. Here is the [link on docs.Kendoui](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html). You can customize it as per below code.

```
filterable: {
    extra: true,
    operators: {
        string: {
            startswith: "Starts with",
            eq: "Is equal to",
            neq: "Is not equal to"
        }
    }
},
```

But I don't think you can change the sequence of `And`/`Or` options in the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help. Ok I was not knowing that we could change the sequence for the And / Or operator. But thanks for the help

Comment: I am not sure about this. You can raise ticket for it to kendo support.

Comment: Ok. will see if that is really the requirement or if we can pass that. Based on that will decide. But really really thanks for your help.